# JQuery toggle slide out tab and click outside to close

Tags: jquery, menu, click

i have a problem with this script:
http://jsfiddle.net/bZw83/

It toggles a tab with language selection in or out the screen if a click occurs inside the tab.
Now i'm stuck, i tried to write a function that toggles the tab out of the screen if the click is outside the tab usin something like

```
$('html').click(function() {...});
```

but i cannot exclude the area of the tab from firing the event.
I tried using event.stopPropagation() but i' not able to achieve the goal :-/

Can someone help me figure this out?

Thank you very much

Comment: try to use not selectors of jquery.......try this link http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp

Comment: @raman can you update your comment and select `not` as source code using backticks? Otherwise it *could* be misread as "*try not to use jQuery selectors*". :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a handler for the document, and then check if it the #navigation or a child of it.

Seee: http://jsfiddle.net/bZw83/1/

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    $target = $(e.target);
    var is = $target.is('#navigation');
    var isChild = $target.parents('#navigation').length;

    if(!(is) && !(isChild)) {
        $('a', $(this)).stop().animate({
            'marginLeft': '-44px'
        }, 200);
        stato = "chiuso";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
 $(document).click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).parents("*").andSelf().is('#navigation')==false)
    {
       //your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by handling the click event for the document, as follows:

```
$(document).click(function() {
   $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-44px'},200);
   stato="chiuso";
});
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/bZw83/3/)